# Adobe Flash CC Publish to AS2

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I have just started using Flash CC, but i cannot seem to publish to AS2.

I have tried looking at the publish options but AS2 does not seem to be there, does this require a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Adobe totally removed AS2 support in Flash CC. It will open a `.fla` with AS2 but remove the code.

You can, however, still download Flash CS6 from the Creative Cloud application portal/site as a legacy workaround.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I still had serious trouble locating the download. Here's the documentation, describing the steps: http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/install-apps.html